# Incorrect vector length after replacing certain values with NA

Tags: r

I encountered this very strange problem:

Say I make the following data frame

```
test<-as.data.frame(matrix(c(2,4,5,2,4,6),2,3,byrow=T))
#      V1 V2 V3
# 1    2  4  5
# 2    2  4  6
```

Then I replace the number 5 in column V3 row 1 with NA:

```
test$V3[test$V3==5]<-NA
#      V1 V2 V3
# 1    2  4 NA
# 2    2  4  6
```

Strangely, now the length of vector with value 6 is incorrect:

```
length(test$V3[test$V3==6])
# 2
```

How come the output is 2 instead of 1?

Comment: "[" has a strange behavior (to my way of thinking) with NA values.

Comment: you could use this `'%=%' <- function(x, y) {z <- x == y; z[is.na(z)] <- FALSE; z}` instead of `==` like so: `length(test$V3[test$V3 %=% 6])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take apart the expression to see what's happening:

```
test$V3==6
# [1]   NA TRUE
```

As you can see, there is an `NA` value for the missing element. This causes an `NA` when subsetting `test$V3`:

```
test$V3[test$V3==6]
# [1] NA  6
```

Since this is a vector of length 2, this explains why your code returns 2.

It sounds like you actually want to count the number of elements equal to 6, ignoring missing values. You could do this with:

```
sum(test$V3 == 6, na.rm=TRUE)
# [1] 1
```

or

```
sum(!is.na(test$V3) & test$V3 == 6)
# [1] 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides the two methods offered so far I will offer a couple more. The first one does the NA removal for you and I find it useful in selection rows from data.frames when I don't want all the garbage rows that "[" drags along with the NA selections:

```
> length(which(test$V3 == 6))
[1] 1
> length(subset(test, V3 == 6, V3))
[1] 1
```

The second one with two "V3" tokens might seem a bit redundant until you realize that without that second "V3" that you would get 3 columns in the one row dataframe.